# Attributes in Dart

Tags: dart

Are there any plans to introduce attributes

for classes, methods, parameters of methods,

something like C# or Java attributes ?

```
    [Test]
    class SomeClass
    {
        [Test]
        someMethod()
    }
```

or

```
    @Test
    class SomeClass
    {
        @Test
        someMethod(@Test int param)
    }
```

For many frameworks it would be very useful

Answer (score 7):

In dart, they are called *metadata* / *annotation*. The syntax is quite close to java. Here's a example :

```
@Test testMethod() {}
```

In Dart Specification you can read :

> Metadata consists of a series of annotations, each of which begin with the character @, followed a constant expression that starts with an identifier. It is a compile time error if the expression is not one of the following:
>
> - A reference to a compile-time constant variable.
> - A call to a constant constructor.
>
> [....]
>
> Metadata can appear before a library, class, typedef, type parameter, constructor, factory, function, field, parameter, or variable declaration and before an import or export directive.

There're already some *annotations* predifined in [dart:core](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core.html). Particulary `@override`, `@deprecated` and `@proxy`.

Comment: Wonderful answer, is there any info on how to work with meta data ? (i.e. using mirrors to access the class meta data ?).

Comment: Thanks, look at the answers of John Evans and Justin Fagnani. They give 2 links containing a lot more informations on metadatas.

Comment: @Lars You can use the analyzer package and dart:mirrors to get information about annotations.

Answer (score 4):

Dart already has annotations, similar to Java in some ways, they're just not used in very many places yet, and they're not accessible from reflection yet either.

See this article: http://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/proposal-to-add-metadata-to-dart.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's a brief introduction to the two metadata annotations currently available in the Dart meta library:

[Dart Metadata is your friend.](http://phylotic.blogspot.com/2012/11/dart-metadata-is-your-friend.html)

This doesn't preclude you from using your own, but these are the two that have tooling integration with the Dart Editor.